# Capture slow query in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm working on some timeout issue in Cassandra production environment
and I have set slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms to 5000 ms in Cassandra.yaml to capture any slow queries in debug.log

The following query captured several times as slow query, interestingly there isn't any similar query in the application, so I'm wondering maybe Cassandra translate syntax of slow query to some specific format!

> SELECT * FROM mainschema.events WHERE id =
> b7450619-d2b2-8ba6-0c48-a9bffeef79c0 AND token(user_id, id) >
> -341911299102519303 AND token(user_id, id) <= -326035898540169815 LIMIT 100>, time 6802 msec - slow timeout 500 msec/cross-node

So my question is how can I capture the actual text of slow query in Cassandra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The monitoring thread which detects queries which took longer than `slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms` aggregates the queries and only logs them every 5 seconds at `DEBUG` level.

As part of the aggregation logic, there is some transformation that occurs so if a query was executed multiple times within that 5-second window then it will only get logged once with a count. For example:

```
DEBUG [ScheduledTasks:1] 2020-06-06 20:35:50,211 MonitoringTask.java:173 - \
    1 operations were slow in the last 4998 msecs:
<SELECT * FROM community.users WHERE user = "jack" LIMIT 5000>, \
    was slow 2 times: avg/min/max 330/825/835 msec - slow timeout 500 msec
```

If you're interested, I've explained this in a bit more detail in this post -- https://community.datastax.com/questions/7835/.

Having said all that, I don't believe this is happening in your case. My suspicion is that the application is doing a range scan but you might not be aware of it. For example, the app could be reading from `mainschema.events` with `ALLOW FILTERING`. That's conjecture on my part but it should give you a clue when you're reviewing the app code for queries against the `events` table. Cheers!